# How to resolve a git conflict when pulling (in eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, git

I accidentally made a mess of and then deleted a java project from eclipse (more specifically, I accidentally moved the classes to a different project and then moved them back, and then deleted the project [from the file system] in eclipse), and now whenever I try to do team -> pull (after running ant -f ...), a window pops up saying that there's a checkout conflict with the files that were deleted. How do I get past this conflict and make pulling work again? I could create a new workspace, checkout everything into there again, and copy the code that I'm currently developing into that workspace, but there must be an easier way. Please educate this git n00b.

Comment: You need to bring your file system in agreement with what git think it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Open the "Git repositories" view (Ctrl 3 -> git repositories), right-click your project, select "reset".

In the following dialog, enter "HEAD" in the "Reset to (expression)" field and select Hard.

This will completly reset your workspace to pristine state.

Now, reimport your deleted project (File -> import... -> Existing project")

Now everything is back to the state before your "mess" and you can pull again.

Comment: Resetting my workspace to a pristine state means that all the code I'm currently developing will disappear, right? (Said code's contained in multiple projects within a branch). If so, I might as well just create a new workspace, so that I don't have to worry about whether I've backed everything up prior to resetting.

Comment: Correct. If you want to save some changes, open the git staging perspective, move the changes to you want to keep into Staged changes and commit them. Leave anything simply sitting in the Unstaged changes area. After the commit, do the "hard reset"

Comment: Ah, that could work! Will try it as soon as I have a chance. Thank you.